# How to deny third-party access to a server side API

Tags: php, json, api, authentication, cloud

I only want my client application to access my server side API (JSON, but it could be any protocol), but even using an authentication system, is there any way I could prevent third parties from reverse engineering the client and getting access to this API?

Comment: You could provide an `access token` when you send requests to your API

Comment: have you tried whitelisting IPs from your client application?

Comment: @KyleEmmanuel Exactly, but because this token is hardcoded in the app, anyone could obtain it by reverse engineering the app or analyzing the network traffic, right?

Comment: @Meow well, you can always randomize the token.

Comment: @KyleEmmanuel How does that work? The randomized token still needs to be understood by the server, and it's still going to be sent through HTTP, which could be easily analyzed... Or maybe I could just use SSL, but it only solves the network analysis part.

Answer (score 1):

If you are connecting to an API via a clients machine, I think in theory there is nothing you can do to keep them from monitoring there own http connections. However, if the client interface is a website, then the website will act as a proxy for your API. This means that unless they get root access on your server, they can't see your API. but if someone gets root access on your server you will probably have much bigger problems than someone finding your API.

on a side note, relatively few people now how to track their own http connections, much less have the desire and know-how to take advantage of it.

Comment: That's what I thought. I guess I was just looking for a magical way of obfuscating the access token from both binary reverse engineering and network traffic analysis.

Comment: Well getting an access token and seeing a http/tcp route are 2 different things. One way to prevent someone from getting access token is to give each access token a timeout period (let say 1 hour) and then make your connections over https with a 128 bit SSL encryption or better. You would need government scale funding in order to break a 128 bit encryption in a reasonable amount of time. And even then I don't think you could do it inside of an hour.